# Create automation macro support within an application

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vba, automation

I need to get an automation macro like thing within our desktop application. The desktop app will probably be in VB.NET or C#.net.
The reason is to enable the user to record and replay certain tasks that they'd like to automate. Something like macros within office apps and visual studio.
The first thing that comes to my mind is VBA.

Is this the right approach or whether are there any other options available?
Any gotchas or things to look out for, if some body has already done it before.
Some helpful links to get me going.

Whatever little help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
Samrat.

P.S. This is a quite generic question not belonging to any specific technology. If some of you think the tags are inappropriate or if it needs some more tags which I missed out, feel free to edit them :)

Comment: and there go my 50 dear ones :(

Comment: Although I advocate the Command Pattern answer from Philipp I wanted to ask, are you fixed on using VBA or .net for the macro code? There are loads of other embeddable scripting languages out there. LUA (http://www.lua.org/) springs to mind.

Comment: @Tony - No. I said VBA is the first thing that I popped in my mind since I was familiar with it in Microsoft products. Although, I didn't know its practicality to integrate and other alternatives that existed. Of course, for now my main aim is automation\macro recording rather than having a full blown scripting language support. I will take a look at LUA. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks otaku, markj and grigori for your inputs. They have been immensely helpful. Although, after much thought, philipp's solution seems more appropriate to my needs, which's also reflected in the number of votes cast, so I grant him this bounty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you thinking of macros that are just for "record-replay" of some consecutive actions? This might be pretty well doable if you use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in your UI programming. Then every user action is described by an object (derived from an abstract Command class having a "execute()" method). Now recording and replaying is simply storing a list of command objects, serializing them and your macro is done. For replaying it you simply deserialize the data and execute the list of commands again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this is basically right. VBA would be overkill if you don't need a general programming language. If you *do* need a general programming language, just using a .NET language would be much less of a pain than finding a way to use VBA.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. I'd probably wait some more days to get a couple of more opinions before accepting this as an answer. None the less I will if something better doesn't show up. Thanks again!

Comment: @jtolle @samrat I think jtolle is right. Integrating VBA into your application would require licensing VBA from Microsoft. It used to be seriously expensive. I believe these days they no longer support it at all in third-party applications.

Comment: For the situation Samrat Patil is describing I agree the command pattern is the way to go. One thing that hasn't been mentioned is the integration of a scripting language in to your app does not happen by magic, you still have to write code to interface to the script or expose objects in a simple way to the script. If there is no requirement for the user to edit the macro after creating it, go with Philipp's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. You're the rightful recipient of these 50 precious ones.

Answer (score 3):

VSTA ([Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Applications)) is the replacement for VBA. It hasn't caught on as much as VBA did with 3rd party vendors or even in MSFT's own products (the only one that currently has it is InfoPath). But it's far more modern than VBA, if that is a concern.

Check out [VSTA main page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700828.aspx), and in particular the video: [Integrating VSTA to Enable Macro Recording](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=6459750).

Comment: now thats awesome! will go through it...shall wait some more time though to see what the others think too...looks like it was worth 50 creds after all :) Thanks Otaku

Comment: +1. I hadn't heard of this before. It should be emphasised that VSTA is not free. Also, personally, I would be wary that Microsoft might drop support in the future. I know one major software vendor, ESRI, [used to use](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcobjectsdevelopment/archive/2009/03/30/VBA-and-VB6_3A00_-The-Road-Ahead.aspx) VBA but now use Python as their scripting language. My guess (and it is only a guess) is that ESRI may have made a strategic decision to avoid Microsoft scripting solutions in future, partly because they are periodically retired. This irritates end users.

Comment: .. another example is Managed JScript. [Introduced by Microsoft in 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2007/05/07/introducing-managed-jscript.aspx) as a "first class language" on the DLR and, whoops, completely dropped within two years. Bad luck for [anyone who used it](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/06/12/Managed-JScript-on-the-DLR-from-Microsoft-is-DEAD-Why.aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ: Yeah, read the first paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications#Future - other failures are listed there. VSTA may have more legs however, especially since it was integrated into Office (it takes an enormous amount of internal political fire power at MSFT to get something into an Office program and once it's there, it's hard to remove).

Comment: @Otaku Another interesting link! Very interesting to see VBA being developed again. I'm sure you're right that VSTA being integrated into Office will give it longevity within Office, just like VBA. But the longevity of VBA within Office hasn't been a great help to third parties who integrated it into their applications. They've been dumped anyway.

Comment: There are also quite a few basic language clones out there, including http://www.thinbasic.com and http://www.kbasic.com/

Comment: I never knew about VSTA being available but after I saw the cost of licenses (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb407600.aspx) I think I'll steer clear and stick with Lua or Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some articles about the topic from MSDN:

[Implement a Microsoft Word-like Object Model for Your .NET Framework Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973253.aspx)

[StickOut: A Desktop Sticky Notes Application in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480731.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be built in your application? There are macro solutions on the Windows level (assuming that's your target OS)

- [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com)
- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/)

Comment: I'm aware of AHK. But I need this to be built into the app which needs to be run on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powershell [cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714598%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Implement each action performed by your GUI as a `cmdlet`. Then the users can use Powershell to script. I believe this is the approach used by [Exchange Server and SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). Of course those are both aimed at [sysadmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysadmin) users

Answer (score 0):

Since you're developing the app yourself, you should be able to use the Windows API directly to create (AND monitor) mouse/keyboard events.

Take a look at [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28VS.85%29.aspx), [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx). They're pretty easy to use properly (I find them more straight forward than using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but thats just my opinion).